# Stripe API calls with TLS 1.2 from Flask

Tags: python, stripe-payments, tls1.2

I'm incorporating Stripe into a Flask server running on localhost. I'm trying to create a new Stripe customer with this code:

```
stripe.api_key = "..."
...
stripeCustomer = stripe.Customer.create()
```

I'm running my server with `flask run` locally right now. I get the following error:

```
Request req_93sOkJgT8QEioq: Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. 
Please initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later.
```

How do I make Stripe API calls using TLS 1.2? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stripe+tls

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks, I'm running this from OSX 10.11.5, just using the default Flask dev server. How do I upgrade this to TLS 1.2?

Comment: read the doc: https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-stripe-integration-from-tls-1-0-to-tls-1-2#python

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks, I've installed python with brew and set it as the default, and I've reinstalled stripe as per the instructions in the doc. However, the error still appears.

Comment: then I recommend you send a message to stripe support, indicating the steps you took to solve the problem.